# Text box validataion for Decimal value

Tags: asp.net

I have an application in which I want to validate a text box that it will take decimal value.
I would like to use a regular expression validator for this. What would this expression look like?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use a regular expression - create a custom validator that uses [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) under the covers.

**Edit:** To be fair to the question, here is a regular expression that would do the trick:

> `^\d*\.?\d+$`

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a regular expression?  Too much?

Comment: I am always hesitant to create a regular expression that will validate input for which there exists a library parsing function (int, decimal, datetime, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

just the regex would be

```
`\d*`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a CompareValidator - for type decimal
And a Required field Validator - so blank is not allowed
But regular expression is accepable this link gives some examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998267.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I say to keep using the Regular Expression Validator, you'll get the added benefit of client-side validation with it.

Here is a list of regular expressions related to decimals:
http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CompareValidator and use Regular Expression

```
^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$
```

This allow all decimal number, exclude all alphanumeric caracter

e.g.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
            ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
            runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Only Decimal Value" 
            ValidationExpression="^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```